# Append new line to data frame in R containing a String

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following R code:

```
example = data.frame(
    cola = c("mySTR1","mySTR2"),    
    colb = c("04-05-2015","04-05-2015"),
    A = c(-1.41,-7.41),     
    B = c(58.08375106,0.001),
    C = c(35.21623542,82.90195247)
)
```

and it gives me the following table:

```
cola       colb     A        B        C 
1 mySTR1 04-05-2015 -1.41 58.08375 35.21624
2 mySTR2 04-05-2015 -7.41  0.00100 82.90195
```

Now I want to add a new line and I am trying it by using the following code:

```
example[3,] = data.frame(
    cola = "STR3",
    colb = "05-05-2015",
    A = -0.58,
    B = 30.68441404,
    C = 50
)
```

and the table returned is:

```
cola       colb     A        B        C
1 STR1 04-05-2015 -1.41 58.08375 35.21624
2 STR2 04-05-2015 -7.41  0.00100 82.90195
3 <NA>       <NA> -0.58 30.68441 50.00000
```

As you can see the cola and colb have NA and the got the following errors:

```
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = 1L) :
 invalid factor level, NA generated
2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = 1L) :
 invalid factor level, NA generated
```

I am having difficulties to understand why the string data becomes NA and how can I do fix it. Can someone help?

Comment: [**Search**](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5br%5d%20R%20invalid%20factor%20level%2c%20NA%20generated) before posting. "This question does not show any research effort"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `rbind()` function, instead of trying to assign the second data frame as the third row of first data frame.

```
add <- data.frame(
    cola = "STR3",
    colb = "05-05-2015",
    A = -0.58,
    B = 30.68441404,
    C = 50
)

rbind(example, add)
```